Response takes too long to be sent back to the browser
So I'm having a problem with the Laravel framework, the problem is that the response takes too long to be sent back to the client.
Let's assume that we have the following piece of code:
<?php

namespace Modules\Task\Http\Controllers\Website;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Modules\Task\Services\Website\TaskService;
use Modules\Task\Transformers\TaskResource;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(private readonly TaskService $taskService)
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = $this->taskService->all();
        return response()->resource(TaskResource::collection($tasks));
    }

}

The line where I call the all() method takes about 10.98 ms to execute, but the overall response time is about 780 ms, which is very strange.
I thought the problem would be that the resource is doing too much work, and perhaps that's what's taking too long, so I removed it altogether and just used the line:
return $tasks;

However, the response wasn't getting any faster, it's still the same.
I thought the problem would be a server misconfiguration, so I created a new empty project and deployed it on the server and it had very small response time, so the problem obviously isn't a server configuration issue.
The operation that takes most of the time is the response send, and I don't have any clues why is this happening.
What do you think the problem may be? And where do you suggest me to look for some clues because I'm truly out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

it might be harder than that to find out what's causing time consuming tasks.. to cite one, the instruction $this->taskService->all() not necessarily tells the whole truth if the model is fetched later when iterating over the collection preforming additional queries.  You may search for eager loading for example so that data gets fetched all at once. Anyway this comment was just an opinion to better focus the issue

@DiegoD Thanks for pointing out. I've created a very simple route that returns a plain string "hello world", and still the response takes too long

low system/server resources, may be ?! does a fresh laravel projects rakes too long to output a response?

Maybe a network issue? Proxy or Loadbalancer involved? Maybe do a profiling of the request to determine the real bottleneck (if any)

@OMiShah Not at all ... A fresh Laravel project will take about 20ms to print the output

@HonkderHase Can you suggest me some good tools to achieve this?
